# How to print with JAX

Tags: jit, jax

I have a JAX Boolean array and want to print a statement combined with sum of *True*s:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.experimental.host_callback import id_print

@jax.jit
def overlaps_jax():
    mask_cp = jnp.array([True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, True])
    id_print(jnp.sum(mask_cp))

overlaps_jax()
```

There are 5 *True*s in the `mask_cp`; I want to print as:

```
With jax accelerator
There are 5 true bools
```

As this function is [jitted](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/196), I tried to print this by using [`id_print`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.experimental.host_callback.id_print.html#jax.experimental.host_callback.id_print), but I couldn't. `id_print(jnp.sum(mask_cp))` will print `5`, but I couldn't use this with the strings. I have tried the followings:

```
id_print(jnp.sum(mask_cp))
# print:
# 5

id_print("\nWith jax accelerator\nThere are " + jnp.sum(mask_cp) + " true bools\n")
# error:
# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "DynamicJaxprTracer") to str

print("\nWith jax accelerator\nThere are {} true bools\n".format(jnp.sum(mask_cp)))
# print:
# With jax accelerator
# There are Traced<ShapedArray(int64[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=0/1)> true bools
```

How could I print such statements in this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that `id_print` is experimental, and its API and capabilities are subject to change. That said, I don't believe `id_print` has the capability to add text like this, but you can do it via a more general `host_callback.call`:

```python
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.experimental.host_callback import call

@jax.jit
def overlaps_jax():
    mask_cp = jnp.array([True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, True])
    call(lambda x: print(f"There are {x} true bools"), jnp.sum(mask_cp))

overlaps_jax()
```

The output is

```
There are 5 true bools
```